# How do I enclose content in an anchor tag and validate?

Tags: html, css

Due to layout requirements I have enclosed an `h4` tag and a `p` tag inside an anchor tag. The problem is this does not validate properly. I need the anchor tag for the link and the mouseover action on the background image.

What is the correct way to do this without breaking the layout?

Here is the HTML:

```
<div class="services">
    <a href="http://corecubed.com/our-services/{url_title}">
        <h4>{home_page_title}</h4>
        <p>{home_page_blurb}</p>
    </a>
</div>
```

Here is the CSS:

```
.services a:link, .services a:visited {
    width: 165px;
    height: 181px;
    display: block;
    color: #5e5e5e;
    text-decoration: none;
    float: left;
    margin: 0 5px 20px 0;
    background: url(/images/bg_services.png) no-repeat center bottom;
}

.services a:hover {
    background-position: center top;
}

.services h4 {
    width: 140px;
    height: 50px;
    display: block;
    font-size: 13px;
    font-weight: normal;
    color: #eaeaea;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 10px 10px 0 15px;
}

.services p { 
    line-height: 19px;
    padding: 0 10px 0 10px; 
}
```

I am open to any solid guidance on this.

Comment: What do you mean by "layout requirements"? If you're forced to use that HTML structure then there's not much you can do about it not validating.

Comment: It doesn't validate because you must not use block elements inside `<a>` tags. I recommend using a javascript solution, that will validate.

Comment: If you can change the HTML and keep the content in the `<a>` tag, I suggest using spans and style than with the already present CSS, that will validate as long as you don't use block elements.

Comment: I'll give it a go with spans and see how it does.

Comment: Hi Jack.joe, your solution works. Please elevate your comment about using spans to an answer and I'll give you credit for it. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

This may not be an issue as HTML progresses.

In HTML5, the `a` tag can enclose both inline and block level elements (phrasing and flow elements respectively).

See: http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/a.html#a

### Example

I used the following snippet:

```
<a href="http://www.yahoo.com">
    <h3>Go see Yahoo...</h3>
    <p>A short paragraph.</p>
</a>
```

and created the following HTML5 page:

http://jsfiddle.net/audetwebdesign/Hm7wp/show/

Using the following validator, http://validator.w3.org, I got a successful result
except for the warning that the HTML5 validator is experimental (work in progress).

You can review the [Validation Results](http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http://jsfiddle.net/audetwebdesign/Hm7wp/show/) and examine the details.

Comment: Hi Marc, I tried changing the doctype to html(5) but I still get the same validation issues.

Comment: @fmz, why did you accept the answer if it did not solve the problem? It should, so please post the complete document you tried to validate.

Comment: @JukkaK.Korpela The comment refers to the OP's document, not the demo document that I created.  I demonstrated a proof-of-concept solution which apparently the OP thought was helpful enough to accept.

Comment: It was contradictory to accept the answer and to comment “I still get the same validation issues”. My guess is that the doctype used was erroneous, perhaps because the answer does not say directly that the doctype string to be used is `<!DOCTYPE html>` and should appear at the very start of the document.

Comment: For some reason in my context, it would not validate until I changed the h4 and p to spans.

Comment: I just put your original snippet through the validator and it does validate: http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A%2F%2Fjsfiddle.net%2Faudetwebdesign%2FSVDn9%2Fshow%2F  Something else is going on that is being affected by something that is not part of your original question.  Without more information such as a link to the page in question, it is hard to guess what is going on.